# Latest Angular upgrade caused NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

A week or two ago, I upgraded Angular to the latest version in the web app that used to work without a hitch. Now, every time we go to the login page (which injects the [once-working] AuthService), the browser returns an error message as follows:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n)[AuthService -> _w -> _w -> _w]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for _w! NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n)[AuthService -> _w -> _w -> _w]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for _w!`

with the origin being traced to polyfill.js. I read that it has something to do with the latest webpack upgrade, but I can't find info on how to fix it. What exactly is going on? How can I remedy this?

When I turned off optimization, I got:

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AuthService -> Auth -> Auth -> Auth]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for Auth!`

which is only marginally more informative.

Comment: You might want to share some of the login code (constructor and its class decorator), and/or the module(s) where the AuthService is provided.

Comment: Have you tried forwardRef? If that didn't work did you try to inject an Injector and then resolving it only when using it? It just sounds like a circular injection

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured out the answer and fixed the problem. Basically, I was importing the `Auth` class in my `AuthService` module, which was appropriate prior to the advent of Angular 13. Now, according to this tutorial:

https://www.positronx.io/full-angular-firebase-authentication-system/

you're supposed to import `AngularFireAuth` from `@angular/fire/compat/auth`. I refactored my code and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The @ Decorator symbol was missing in front of

```
Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

After refactoring code placing my `const` variables above the `@Injectable`, the problem was solved.
So I had this

```
const AUTH_LOGIN = gql`
  mutation Login($username: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(data: {password: $password, username: $username, phone: "", domain: "transnational"}) {
      response
    }
  }
  `;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting production to true in environment.prod.ts solved my issue.

```
export const environment = {
  firebase: {
    projectId: '',
    appId: '',
    databaseURL: '',
    storageBucket: '',
    apiKey: '',
    authDomain: '',
    messagingSenderId: '',
    measurementId: '',
  },
  production: true
};
```